# Hatched egg question

Tags: pokemon-go

I hatched an egg. It had the question mark on it. Then my app froze and I had to shut my phone off. When I turned my phone back on it said I had one less egg and the egg hatched. How do I find the hatched egg to see which Pokemon it was?

Comment: So what does that mean? Is it lost?

Comment: It means check your recent Pokemon, it should be there.

Answer (score 1):

If you open your pokemon menu, you can sort by recent pokemon. They have a blue circular background. If you're not sure which pokemon it is, you can have a look at their candy level.

Hatching pokemon usually awards more candy so you could recognize by bigger-than-expected value.

Sadly journal doesn't show hatched pokemon.

Comment: Journal now shows hatched Pokemon after recent updates.